# Laravel charts - display values inside graphs

Tags: laravel, charts

I'm trying to implement a chart on a webpage (laravel) using laravel charts library (version 6 I can't use the newer version because of the PHP version). Looks not bad but I would like to display values inside blocks, and I don't find an option which does the job.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67o9r.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8I4g.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems has you using Laravel and even Vue. My solution was to use a JavaScript library that does the job of drawing charts very well.
I strongly recommend you to use [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org).

```
...
<head>
    // Import of the latest ChartJS <link> and <script>
</head>    

<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="myChartFour"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ctxFour = document.getElementById('myChartFour').getContext('2d');
        var myChartFour = new Chart(ctxFour, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: {
                labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Number of Color Votes',
                    data: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ]
                }]
            },
        });
    </script>
</body>
...
```

**The implementation of showing values inside a Pie Chart it's not supported by ChartJS.** However you can still do it if in some way you create HTML elements with an absolute position. Then you can determine wich coordenates this elements must have in order to stay on top of the correct Pie Chart slice.

This approach is only reliable for the same screen resolution. With other different screen resolutions the absolute positioned HTML elements might or will be out of place. Therefore this approach it's not good for Responsive Web Design.

**In the end what you are trying to do it's not possible with ChartJs. But it's possible with criative harcoded HTML and CSS tricks.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I found something looks similar there https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html , but i still don't see option or something to do this job

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do the job that way. It is possible that donut chart doesn't support what you want to do with it. . . You are welcome!